# Using get_the_excerpt in edit-post

Tags: php, post-editor

I'm trying to use get_the_excerpt in edit-post to show show what a post will look like on the front-end, but it doesn't work. All other get_the_xxxx functions for the post works fine. I can show the title, date, metadata, but not the excerpt for some reason.

I tried this, didnt work either:

```
$text = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));
```

Is there something preventing me from using get_the_excerpt on the edit-post page?

Comment: I can use get_the_excerpt on the front-end and it works fine. But on the edit-post page it returns nothing. If there is no custom excerpt created it should just get the first n words/characters from the post, which it does on the front-end.

Comment: Yes but global $post is maybe not reachable in your function. You should try to add it if you don't (global $post; at the top of the function)

Answer (score 0):

I think (and assuming) you use (without code, it's hard to know, how you proceed) `add_meta_boxes()` to do your job. Then your code is logically standing in custom functions.

Your function to render the metabox, don't get the `$post` global, if you didn't define it, the function need to know from which post it must retrieve the excerpt, so you need to add `global $post;` this should work

```
function get_excerpt_custom_metabox(){
    global $post;

    echo get_the_excerpt();
}
```

The way you want to use the_excerpt filter is not the right way. You must do it like this

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'your_excerpt_function', 10, 2);

function your_excerpt_function($excerpt, $post_id){
    // do what you want,

    return $excerpt;
}
```

Don't hesitate to update your question with more code, if you think I'm wrong.